# How to write output of web scrape to column instead of rows in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, csv, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to write the results of scraping a webpage to a CSV file. I have successfully written the output to CSV but it went in as rows instead of columns. Here is the script:

```
import bs4
import requests
import csv

#get webpage for Apple inc. September income statement
page = requests.get("https://au.finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s=AAPL")

#put into beautiful soup
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.content)

#select table that holds data of interest
table = soup.find("table", class_="yfnc_tabledata1")

#creates generator that holds four values that are yearly revenues for company
revenue = table.tr.td.table.tr.next_sibling.td.next_siblings

#iterates through generator from above and writes output to CSV file
for value in revenue:
    value = value.get_text(strip=True)
    with open('/home/kwal0203/Desktop/Apple.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
            s = csv.writer(csvfile)
            s.writerow([data.encode("utf-8") for data in [value]])
```

I understand there is a `zip()` function in Python that may be of use but haven't been able to figure out how I can apply it to this situation.

Thanks any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the file only once and call `writerow()` only once:

```
with open('/home/kwal0203/Desktop/Apple.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow([value.get_text(strip=True).encode("utf-8") for value in revenue])
```

Produces:

```
"37,432,000","45,646,000","57,594,000","37,472,000"
```

---

Bonus to improve the answer: you can also parse the table headers and write them as csv headers:

```
headers = table.find('tr', class_="yfnc_modtitle1").find_all('th')
revenue = table.tr.td.table.tr.next_sibling.td.next_siblings

with open('/home/kwal0203/Desktop/Apple.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow([value.get_text(strip=True).encode("utf-8") for value in headers])
    writer.writerow([value.get_text(strip=True).encode("utf-8") for value in revenue])
```

Produces:

```
27/09/2014,28/06/2014,29/03/2014,28/12/2013
"42,123,000","37,432,000","45,646,000","57,594,000"
```

Comment: This is brilliant thanks. Is there anyway to get rid of the quotation marks?

Comment: @Kane thanks, it is because of the commas inside the values. Which option would you choose: replace commas with dots, or use a different delimiter, like `|`?

Comment: the commas are fine I meant the quotation marks `""` those ones

Comment: @Kane yeah, I understand. I'm trying to say that the `CSV` delimiter is, by default, comma, and there are commas inside the values. In order to distinguish commas inside the values with the delimiter comma - it puts the values in quotes.

Comment: Oh I see, I guess `|` would be fine. Will the `|` symbols be visible on the CSV output? like this: `|42,123,000|`?

Comment: @Kane yup, then just set the `delimiter` this way: `writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='|')`.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, **zip** can easily help you here:

```
#creates generator that holds four values that are yearly revenues for company
revenue = table.tr.td.table.tr.next_sibling.td.next_siblings

revenue = zip(*revenue) # <------ yes, it is that easy

#iterates through generator from above and writes output to CSV file
for value in revenue:
    value = value.get_text(strip=True)
         ...
```